# jquery datepicker - activate another datepicker on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have 2 jquery datepickers to select a date range.

Once I have selected a from date (from the first datepicker), I would like to activate the second (to) datepicker.

The code below does that, but for some reason closes the datepicker straight away.

Any ideas? - http://jsfiddle.net/rN4zu/

```
From <input type="text" id="dateFrom" />
To <input type="text" id="dateTo" />
```

jQuery

```
$( "#dateFrom" ).datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: "+2Y",
    showWeek: true,
    weekHeader: 'Wk',
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#dateTo" ).datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate ).focus();
    }
});

$( "#dateTo" ).datepicker({
    maxDate: "+2Y",
    showWeek: true,
    weekHeader: 'Wk'
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8YTKR/

The problem has to do with commands ramping up against each other. The set min date command and `.focus` are happening at the same time, which is causing the problem.

Ok, so first of all `.focus` is not the preferred way of triggering a datepicker. The preferred way is to use the datapicker show method which looks like this `.datepicker('show');`. So in this example we are going to use that instead.

Next we need to make sure that `'show'` occurs AFTER the min date command. And because that command has no callback I am going to use setTimeout

```
$( "#dateFrom" ).datepicker({
    minDate: 0, 
    maxDate: "+2Y",
    showWeek: true,
    weekHeader: 'Wk',
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#dateTo" ).datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        setTimeout(function(){
            $( "#dateTo" ).datepicker('show');
        }, 16);     
    }
});

$( "#dateTo" ).datepicker({
    maxDate: "+2Y",
    showWeek: true,
    weekHeader: 'Wk'
});
```

Why 16ms you say? Because its the longest delay possible without it showing up on screen. 16ms is the default jquery animate interval for this very reason.

Comment: I am doing so. I post as soon as the fiddle was ready, and then write the explanation as an edit.

Comment: Not entirely sure it matters either way as long as a good results comes from it in the end.

Comment: @Tom it makes voting hard.  JSFiddle code without explanation - bad.  Explanation and/or fix with fiddle added later - good!

Comment: @Alnitak I do that because I don't know the situation of the asker. Sometimes it's down right frantic, so as soon as I have code ready I post.

Comment: @Fresheyeball FWIW, it seems jQuery UI monkey patches the `.focus()` method to do exactly the same, but uses a zero timeout.

Comment: I don't recommend 0 for the timeout. With 0 it  you can have the same problem, it just won't happen every time. 0 timeout means 'do it right now' which imho defeats the purpose. I have added an explanation for why 16 is the magic number in javascript.

Answer (score 3):

```
$( "#dateTo" ).datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate ).focus(0);
```

Comment: this seems to work, but I don't understand why as there's no documented numeric parameter to `.focus()`.  Please explain!

Comment: I was about to say the same thing @Alnitak !!

Comment: @Tom ah, it's a jQuery UI extension.  It does the same thing as fresheyeball's answer - it uses `setTimeout` to defer the `focus` until after the current datepicker has finished hiding itself.

Comment: @Tom it also appears to be undocumented - I had to read the source to find it.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion would be to allow the user to pick any date that they would like in either datepicker, then do a validation on both text boxes after the dates are chosen.

The problem with setting the date range in the second datepicker from the value in the first datepicker is if a user chooses , say July 21 by accident, then the second date picker will start at July 21 , but then when they go to change the first date picker to July 1 , the second date picker will be stuck at dates after July 21

Comment: you'll see @Rishi answer will have to problem that I described

Comment: I used @Rishi answer and couldn't get the problem you described.

Comment: if it works , use it , I just found that problem in the past using datepicker in certain browsers