# Display jQuery datepicker after onSelect is executed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use jQuery datepicker 1.11.4 and use two calendars. After select date on first i just wanna select second calendar and show it, but calendar is showing for a second and hiding after that. Something is changing hes "display" (css property) to "none".

Here is my code:

```
$("#edit-to--2").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'D, dd M',
  showAnim: "slideDown",
  changeYear: true
});
$('#edit-from--2').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'D, dd M',
  changeYear: true,
  showAnim: "slideDown",
  minDate: new Date(),
  onSelect: function () {
     var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
     date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
     $("#edit-to--2").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
     $("#edit-to--2").datepicker("show");
  }
});
```

Comment: a running snippet of the problem would have helped more.

Comment: `$("#edit-to--2").focus();` instead of `$("#edit-to--2").datepicker("show");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening as there is an internal animation interval(13ms) you could try to debug. You can use `.focus()` or `Timeout` functionality in which you show date  with timeout more than that of animation interval.

```
$(function(){

$("#edit-to--2").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'D, dd M',
  showAnim: "slideDown",
  changeYear: true
});
$('#edit-from--2').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'D, dd M',
  changeYear: true,
  showAnim: "slideDown",
  minDate: new Date(),
  onSelect: function () {
    debugger;
     var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
     date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
     $("#edit-to--2").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
       setTimeout(function(){$("#edit-to--2").datepicker("show") }, 13); 
  }
});
});
```

source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11653716/3449045

Codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qYerGd

Please do google before asking question.

Hope this helps.

Edit1 : Fixed Links.

Comment: *source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11653716/3449045 Please do google before asking question.*, then you should be closing the question as a duplicate instead of posting an answer ;)